# What are the pros and cons of adding additional functions/combinators to a typeclass definition?

Tags: haskell, typeclass

Looking at the [source for Monad](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/src/GHC-Base.html#Monad):

```
class  Monad m  where
    (>>=)       :: forall a b. m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
    (>>)        :: forall a b. m a -> m b -> m b

    return      :: a -> m a
    fail        :: String -> m a

    {-# INLINE (>>) #-}
    m >> k      = m >>= \_ -> k   -- <-- !! right here !!
    fail s      = error s
```

You can see that `>>` has a default implementation.  My question is, is it considered good or bad practice, and why, to include a function/combinator *in* the typeclass, instead of providing it separately outside of the typeclass?

---

That is, why not:

```
class  Monad m  where
    (>>=)       :: forall a b. m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b

    return      :: a -> m a
    fail        :: String -> m a

    fail s      = error s
```

and somewhere else:

```
(>>)        :: forall a b. m a -> m b -> m b
{-# INLINE (>>) #-}
m >> k      = m >>= \_ -> k
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As far as I know, there are two main reasons to include "extra" functions:

- **Efficiency**: Sometimes an inefficient generic implementation exists, and the class's author expects instance-specific implementations to be significantly better. In such cases, including the function in the class with a default implementation means that instances can use optimized versions if they want, but aren't required to. For a fun example of this, look at `Foldable`. This is also true of `Monad`.
- **Choice of implementation**: Often there are several subsets of the class functions that could be used; including all the potential functions and using default implementations in terms of each other means that an instance can pick some functions to implement and get the rest automatically. This also applies to `Foldable`, but `Eq` is a simpler example.

Comment: Could you also list the *disadvantages*?

Comment: @TikhonJelvis: To be honest, I'm not really sure what objective disadvantages there *are*. It arguably obfuscates the nature of the class a bit, and maybe bloats the class dictionary GHC uses internally, but if there are any obvious, outright disadvantages I'm not aware of them.

Comment: That's what I thought too. But it's curious because, as far as I can tell, these default implementations are used fairly infrequently.

Comment: @C.A.McCann I would say the disadvantage of including more _methods_ in a class is that it may reduce the number of possible implementations; e.g. `Monoid` is a nice typeclass but so is `Semigroup`. (Of course, this doesn't apply to _combinators_ -- only to methods with conceptually different needs than any of the other methods.)

Comment: @DanielWagner: Of course, but only such combinators are at issue here, something which is admittedly not clear from my answer without context of the question...

Answer (score 3):

This way, custom `>>` can be implemented for monads where it can be done more efficiently or naturally than via `m >>= \_ -> k`, but a default implementation still exists.

Answer (score 3):

Another argument for including methods in the typeclass is when they should satisfy certain laws, or when they make the statement of those laws clearer. I would argue that the laws ought morally to be associated with the typeclass ("what must I provide in order to declare an instance of this class?") For example, you might prefer to state the monad laws in terms of `return`, `join` and `fmap`, rather than `return` and `>>=`; that encourages you to put all four operators in the type class (and make `Monad` a subclass of `Functor`!), and give default definitions of `>>=` in terms of `join` and vice versa.`